# Criar arquivos a partir de um template

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Não sei se minha pergunta é inteligente e se é possível fazer o quero. 
Preciso automatizar a criação de arquivos no Visual Studio, aqui na empresa, sempre que criamos uma VIEW é necessário que mais dois arquivos sejam criados [NOME-DA-VIEW].main.js e [NOME-DA-VIEW].controller.js, eles seguem possuem praticamente o mesmo código fonte, porém com algumas peculiaridades.

Alguém tem uma fonte de material a respeito? Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você terá que criar seu próprio *Scaffolder* pra isso. Isso pode ser feito [usando o **Sidewaffle**](http://sidewaffle.com/), uma extensão que cria outras extensões para o Visual Studio.

[Aqui tem um vídeo que pode ser bastante instrutivo do Mads Kristensen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4VaORKgrOw) explicando como fazer sua própria extensão.

[Aqui tem um excelente tutorial para desenvolver seu próprio plugin com os itens de *template*](https://blogs.endjin.com/2014/07/a-step-by-step-guide-to-developing-visual-studio-item-templates-using-sidewaffle/).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, você poderia me dizer se o sidewaffle permite que eu automatize partes do código? Exemplo: Eu quero que ele inclua no arquivo uma função que tenha o nome do arquivo.

Comment: Sim, você pode, inclusive, pedir para o SideWaffle processar *templates* T4.

Comment: Você me indicaria algum livro ou algum outro material mais completo? Fiz uma consulta rápida agora e só encontrei conteúdo raso. Obrigado!

Comment: @Cleiton Coloquei um link pra você na resposta.